# What is the frequency of response of a FDX-B RFID Tag protocol?

Tags: rf, rfid, nfc, tag

I am using the HTRC110 IC for driving the antenna, and the responses are always controlled by the SCLK signal. But when I send the command to read the RFID response, the IC enters in a transparent mode and the frequency and codification of the signal changes...
So, I would like to know if any of you knows this frequency and/or codification.

Answer (score 2):

As defined by the ISO 11784/11785 standards, FDX-B is 134.2 kHz.  FDX-A is 125 kHz.